# IE 8: Only Show Secure Content

Tags: web-applications, ssl, apache-shindig

I manually modified a Shindig App's XML file so that it would grab resources from `https://<my url>` rather than `http://<my url>`.

When I navigate over SSL to my page where the Shindig App lives, I get the `"Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely?"`

When I click `No`, I see the App render as `"The webpage cannot be found."`

However, I can navigate to the Shindig App's XML file.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open a fiddler, and watch all the requests. files of: js, css, html, images, ALL of these must be served via https for this warning to go away. i imagine right now the html is being served https but everything else is still being included as regular http.